# Что происходит "внутри" при обращении к статическому методу не статического класса?

Tags: c#

Имеем не статический класс. Что происходит под капотом при первом и последующих вызовах статического метода этого класса? Язык - c#

Создаётся ли "единый" статический экземпляр класса?

Или код выполняется иным способом

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вопрос можно отредактировать и дополнить, а не дописывать в комментариях.

Comment: Если класс имеет статические члены, то для такого класса выделяется область для хранения членов данного класса. Причем эта область гарантированно "заполняется" .NET-средой в промежутке между запуском программы и первым вызовом статического члена.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Что происходит под капотом при первом и последующих вызовах статического метода этого класса? Язык - c#

Ничего особенного, в сущности. Тут скорее надо ставить вопрос по другому, что **не** происходит, по сравнению с вызовом метода экземпляра. Если взять код `Test.TestStatic("Hello, world");`, то на уровне IL он будет представлен так:

```
ldstr      "Hello, world"
call       void Test::TestStatic(string)
```

То есть аргументы загружаются в стек, и управление передается вызываемому методу. Экземпляр класса нигде не фигурирует. Первый вызов будет отличаться только в случае, если это вообще первое обращение к классу за все время выполнения программы - тогда перед ним будет вызван статический конструктор и проинициализированы статические поля. Остальные вызовы идентичны.

Для сравнения, вызов метода экземпляра:

```
ldloc.0
ldstr      "Hello, world"
callvirt   instance void Test::TestInstance(string)
```

Первая инструкция здесь загружает в стек ссылку на экземпляр класса (который хранится в локальной переменной 0) - она играет роль неявного первого параметра. Инструкция `callvirt` генерируется компилятором C# вместо `call` в том контексте, где ссылка на экземпляр может потенциально быть null, даже если метод не виртуальный, чтобы обеспечить корректную проверку на null и генерацию NullReferenceException. Но для вызова метода экземпляра может использоваться и `call`.